Can we find the quantum state using the Bloch vector in the Bloch sphere?
I had a question about qft. When we apply QFT in a circuit, we can display the qubits separately in the bloch sphere with the plot_bloch_multivector function. I realized that the bloch vectors do not show the quantum states here. I tried to add it to the function myself, but I think it was not consistent.Did I make a mistake while converting the Bloch vector to a quantum state?
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector
from qiskit.visualization.library import _generate_circuit_library_visualization
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector
from qiskit.visualization.state_visualization import _bloch_multivector_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit.visualization.utils import matplotlib_close_if_inline
from __future__ import unicode_literals


from qiskit.visualization.state_visualization import state_to_latex
def my_plot_bloch_multivector(state,title="",figsize=None,*,reverse_bits=False,filename=None,font_size=None,title_font_size=None,title_pad=1):
    import matplotlib

    # Data
    bloch_data = (_bloch_multivector_data(state)[::-1] if reverse_bits else _bloch_multivector_data(state))
    num = len(bloch_data)

    
    matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
    
    if figsize is not None:
        width, height = figsize
        width *= num
    else:
        width, height = plt.figaspect(1 / num)
    default_title_font_size = font_size if font_size is not None else 16
    title_font_size = title_font_size if title_font_size is not None else default_title_font_size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
    for i in range(num):
        pos = num - 1 - i if reverse_bits else i
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, num, i + 1, projection="3d")
        x, y, z = bloch_data[i]
        
        bloch_vector = np.array([x,y,z])
        theta = np.arccos(bloch_vector[2])
        phi = np.arcsin(bloch_vector[1]/np.sin(theta))
        state_vector = Statevector(np.array([np.cos(theta / 2),np.exp(1j * phi) * np.sin(theta / 2) ])).data
        
        # Position the label slightly offset from the Bloch vector tip
        ax.text(x, y, z,state_vector, fontsize=font_size, color='blue', ha='center')
        plot_bloch_vector(bloch_data[i], "qubit " + str(pos), ax=ax, figsize=figsize, font_size=font_size)
    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=title_font_size, y=0.7 + title_pad / 100)
    matplotlib_close_if_inline(fig)
    if filename is None:
        return fig
    else:
        return fig.savefig(filename)




def qubit_state_decomposition(state_vector : Statevector):
    
    n_qubits = state_vector.num_qubits
    individual_qubit_states = []
    
    for qubit_idx in range(n_qubits):
        
        trace_out_qubits = [i for i in range(n_qubits) if i != qubit_idx]
        qubit_state = partial_trace(state_vector, trace_out_qubits)
        individual_qubit_states.append(qubit_state)

    return individual_qubit_states

state = "101"


my_circuit = QuantumCircuit(len(state))

my_circuit.initialize(Statevector.from_label(state).data,my_circuit.qubits[::-1])

computational_statevector = Statevector.from_instruction(my_circuit)



print("Basis States :")
#print(qubit_decomposition(computational_statevector))


display(my_plot_bloch_multivector(computational_statevector.data))

print("\nFourier States :")  
my_circuit.append(QFT(len(state)),my_circuit.qubits)

fourier_statevector = Statevector.from_instruction(my_circuit)
#print(qubit_decomposition(fourier_statevector))
display(my_plot_bloch_multivector(fourier_statevector.data))


Display of the situations occurring for state 101:

I also tried to show the quantum state in the Bloch sphere as a label in latex format, but I could not succeed.

I think I found the answer.Since the plot_bloch_vector method does not have the ability to add labels when creating a Bloch Sphere, labeling cannot be done externally when the Bloch class is instantiated.After instantiating the Bloch class in the plot_bloch_vector method, I manually added the label of the quantum state using the add_annotation method in the Bloch class.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector
from qiskit.visualization.library import _generate_circuit_library_visualization
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT
import warnings
import numpy as np
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def my_plot_bloch_vector(bloch, title="", ax=None, figsize=None, coord_type="cartesian", font_size=None):
    
    from qiskit.visualization.bloch import Bloch
    from qiskit.visualization.state_visualization import _state_to_latex_ket

    if figsize is None:
        figsize = (5, 5)
    B = Bloch(axes=ax, font_size=font_size)
    if coord_type == "spherical":
        r, theta, phi = bloch[0], bloch[1], bloch[2]
        bloch[0] = r * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
        bloch[1] = r * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
        bloch[2] = r * np.cos(theta)

    x, y, z = bloch
    theta = np.arccos(z)
    phi = np.arctan2(y,x)
    alpha = np.cos(theta / 2)
    beta =  np.sin(theta / 2) * np.exp(1j * phi)
    state_vector = Statevector([alpha,beta])
    state_vector_latex = _state_to_latex_ket(state_vector,decimals=10)
    state_vector_latex = r"$\mathbf{{{}}}$".format(state_vector_latex)
    B.add_vectors(bloch)
    B.add_annotation(state_or_vector=np.array([x-0.1 if x < 0 else x+0.1,y-0.1 if y < 0  else y+0.1,z + 0.05 if z < 0 else z+0.1]),
                     text= state_vector_latex,fontsize = 13,color="blue",ha="center")
    B.render(title=title)
    if ax is None:
        fig = B.fig
        fig.set_size_inches(figsize[0], figsize[1])
        matplotlib_close_if_inline(fig)
        return fig
    return None



def my_plot_bloch_multivector(state,title="",figsize=None,*,reverse_bits=False,filename=None,font_size=None,title_font_size=None,title_pad=1):
    import matplotlib
    from qiskit.visualization.state_visualization import _bloch_multivector_data
    from qiskit.visualization.utils import matplotlib_close_if_inline

    # Data
    bloch_data = (_bloch_multivector_data(state)[::-1] if reverse_bits else _bloch_multivector_data(state))
    num = len(bloch_data)
    
    if figsize is not None:
        width, height = figsize
        width *= num
    else:
        width, height = plt.figaspect(1 / num)
    default_title_font_size = font_size if font_size is not None else 16
    title_font_size = title_font_size if title_font_size is not None else default_title_font_size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
    for i in range(num):
        pos = num - 1 - i if reverse_bits else i
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, num, i + 1,projection="3d")
        x, y, z = bloch_data[i]
        theta = np.arccos(z)
        phi = np.arctan2(y,x)
        alpha = np.cos(theta / 2)
        beta =  np.sin(theta / 2) * np.exp(1j * phi)
        state_vector = Statevector([alpha,beta]).data

        # Position the label slightly offset from the Bloch vector tip
        my_plot_bloch_vector(bloch_data[i], "qubit " + str(pos), ax=ax, figsize=figsize, font_size=font_size)
    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=title_font_size, y=0.7 + title_pad / 100)
    matplotlib_close_if_inline(fig)
    if filename is None:
        return fig
    else:
        return fig.savefig(filename)


def qubit_state_decomposition(state_vector : Statevector):
    
    n_qubits = state_vector.num_qubits
    individual_qubit_states = []
    
    for qubit_idx in range(n_qubits):
        
        # Hangi qubitin izleri ile hesaplanacağı belirlenir.
        #(Hangi qubitin indirgenmiş yoğunluk matrisi buluncaksa o qubit dışındaki diğer qubitlerin izi kullanılır.)
        trace_out_qubits = [i for i in range(n_qubits) if i != qubit_idx] 

        
        qubit_state = partial_trace(state_vector, trace_out_qubits)
        individual_qubit_states.append(qubit_state)

    return individual_qubit_states



from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from __future__ import unicode_literals



state = "101"

my_circuit = QuantumCircuit(len(state))

my_circuit.initialize(Statevector.from_label(state).data,my_circuit.qubits[::-1])

computational_statevector = Statevector.from_instruction(my_circuit)



print("Basis States :")


display(my_plot_bloch_multivector(computational_statevector.data))

print("\nFourier States :")  
my_circuit.append(QFT(len(state)),my_circuit.qubits)

fourier_statevector = Statevector.from_instruction(my_circuit)

display(my_plot_bloch_multivector(fourier_statevector.data))


Output :

